# How can I display an empty ImageView with a plus sign in the middle of it

Tags: android

I in see many apps where the user can upload a profile picture, there is an empty frame with a plus in it. where the user clicks and then it loads the gallary etc.

It seems pretty universal on how it looks and behaves with a thumbnail loading inside the image etc so I am wondering if there is a widget or custom view that these apps use. if not then can someone give me an idea on how to implement this from scratch.

Answer (score 2):

Make the empty imageview clickable with onClick method containing sth like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), 100 );
```

Then in

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode == 100 && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
        Uri _uri = data.getData();

        //User picked an image.
        Cursor cursor = getActivity()
                .getContentResolver()
                .query(_uri, new String[] { android.provider.MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA }, null, null, null);

        cursor.moveToFirst();

        //Link to the image
        final String imageFilePath = cursor.getString(0);
        myAvatar = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFilePath);
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) yourView.findViewById(R.id.yourview);
        iv.setImageBitmap(myAvatar);
        cursor.close();
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Comment: This method doesn't show empty frame with plus sign